# How can I create multiple XML files in C# when a stored procedure that is called returns a large number of rows?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, linq

Currently, I am developing a console application which does the following:

1. Executes a SQL Server stored procedure to get data like a mobile phone number, etc..
2. Creates one or multiple XML files with the following catch - there can only be a maximum of 100 elements per file.

So imagine the below:

I have a `Car` class, and the `Car` class as the following properties:

```
Make, Year, Model, Color, Number Of Axles
```

Then I have a

```
List<Car> myCars = new List<Car>();
```

The `Car` class is now populated by the stored procedure, and in the console application code I use the default constructor, populate the list, etc...

I find that `myCars.Count = 200`. I want to have two XML files that would look like this:

```
<!--First xml file-->
<myCars>
     <!-- first set of 100 cars-->
</myCars>
```

Then the second file

```
<!-- Second xml file-->
<myCars>
    <!-- second set of 100 cars from the myCars list -->
</myCars>
```

I am using the `XDocument` and the Linq to XML technology. Please help!

Comment: Since you are using LINQ, you can select the first 100 and create an XML based on the first result, and following the same logic, create the other xml...

Comment: Can you give me a code example of this? I understand what you are saying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use XmlSerializer to create xml of your cars. Select in batch of 100 to create new xml file for that set.

Something like this:

```
 XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Car>));
 int carsPerFile = 100;
 int fileIndex = 1;
 for(int i=0; i<myCars.Count; )
 {
    var cars = myCars.Skip(i).Take(carsPerFile);
    using (var text = XmlWriter.Create(string.Contact("myCars_",fileIndex++,".xml"))
    {
        ser.Serialize(text, cars.ToList());
    }
    i += carsPerFile;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create partitions from a collection with

```
int partitionSize = 100;
var partitions = collection
    .Select( (e,i) => new { Partition = i / partitionSize, Element = e } )
    .ToLookup( e => e.Partition, e => e.Element );
```

and then serialize each partition into a file

```
foreach ( var partition in partitions )
{
    var filename = string.Format( "file_{0}.xml", partition.Key ));
    // write the partition to the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Car> firstHundred = myCars.Take(100); // first 100
List<Car> secondHundred = myCars.Skip(100).Take(100) // 100-200
```

Then serialize these two lists to a different xml file.

Comment: Then how would I be able to have the standard header inserted then? Like below: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>, 

Also ensure to put in the document type declaration?  That is why I was using XDocument originally.

Comment: You should look at the answer of @loopedcode If you serialize like that the header  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> will be included.

Comment: Thank you all so much! Actually @loopedcode provided what I was looking for